# C# UL and >> operators

Tags: c#, operators

What does this meaning mean in words?

```
(SomeVariable * 330UL >> 10)
```

Is it: SomeVariable times 3.3 shift right 10 bit??

Comment: Why don't you run it through the debugger and see what comes out the other end?

Comment: @chris, seems to me like a very bad practice to try executing code before fully formal theoretical understanding of its meaning. This is good for coders (aka prototypers), not developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-shifting an integral value by one is equivalent to dividing it by 2.  Two shifts equivalent to dividing by 4.  Etcetera.  Which makes the expression equivalent to:

```
ulong value = ((ulong)SomeVariable * 330) / 1024;
```

Answer (score 5):

No.

It means SomeVariable times 330, promote to long and shift non-cyclically right  10bits.

(it would be cyclic, or arithmetic shift without the promotion).

Comment: @Pavel Radzivilovsky > The UL promotes the 330 and not the result, right? The result will be long or `SomeVariable`'s type, whichever is more precise. Why isn't it cyclic? I don't understand this, is it: because of the datatype; because it is defined in the language that promoted types don't shift cyclically; something else?

Comment: 330UL is not promotion, it is just the type of the literal. Promotion is due to the type of the argument 330UL. This, makes the result unsigned, and the unsigned operand of >> makes it a non-arithmetic shift.

Answer (score 1):

UL stands for Unsigned Long. >> yes it is bitwise arithmetic shift.

Answer (score 1):

SomeVariable times 330 as an unsigned long shift right 10 bits